# Why is "bioroide/bioroido/bioroid" used in different animes?

Tags: tropes, japanese-language, terminology

In the 1984 anime series Super Dimensional Calvary Southern Cross, there are some alien mechas called "bioroid/bioroido/bioloyd" (depending on the translation) [Bioroids SDC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NdQyWewB7A). In Appleseed there is an artificial species called bioroide [Appleseed Bioroid](http://appleseed.wikia.com/wiki/Bioroid). And apparently in this anime I don't know [Armitage III](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqLNTSDoSCg) there is also a song called Bioroid so I assume there is something called Bioroid in this anime. Where does this word come from? Does it come from anime, does it come from japanese or does it come from sci-fi? Personally I've only heard it in japanese animes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Bioroid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bioroid) is a word depicting a artificially created, cybernetic or biologically organism. Where the roid stands for [android](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/android) and bio for [bio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bio-).

This term is mainly used within the sci-fi genres, one which is broadly covered by anime's as well.

So to to answer your question `Why is “bioroide/bioroido/bioroid” used in different animes?`

It is term used within the sci-fi genre to depict artificially created cybernetics.